# Is it necessary to repeat compilation flags when linking a program?

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, g++, gnu-make

Do g++ flags such as `-O` for optimization and `-g` for creating debugging symbols affect anything during the linking process?

More specifically, if I separate compilation and linking (for instance, in a make file), and I provide the `-O` and `-g` flags during compilation, should I also provide those flags when linking?

Comment: -g is for generating debug symbols, -O optimes i.e. chuks away things that you won't have in the release version. You are not supposed to use -g if you want optimisation, but your choice. If you are using make files you shouldn't have to do this once you have done it in compilation stage.

Comment: @hagubear: `-g` is often useful even for optimised code - it makes the executable a little larger, but generally doesn't affect performance, and it helps with debugging (some bugs only show up in optimised code) and profiling (there is no point profiling unoptimised code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally, this has been unnecessary. Recent improvements in compilers, however, do let at least optimisations also run at link-time: LTO (link-time optimisation) causes the compiled object files to contain intermediate code, not machine code, and that intermediate code will be compiled to machine code at link time, where optimisations can be applied that would be invalid if each object file itself contained machine code. That second step of compilation is affected by command-line options such as `-O`, so you should include them on the command-line when linking.